# Cannot see the Gatsby website running on AWS EC2 Ubuntu server, externally

Tags: amazon-web-services, gatsby

I am trying to see the website running with Gatsby on AWS EC2 Ubuntu Server.

1. Locally website is successfully running with `gatsby develop`
2. I currently have no domain name purchased such that just want to check if the site can be accessible externally.
3. without using surge command, just want to check the website externally.
4. Security groups on AWS EC2 is appropriately configures (Inbound's HTTP/HTTPS are allowed)

In rails I recollect with passing additional parameters it can be accessed externally,

how it works on gatsby? any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ah sorry guys the issue solved.

I used surge with `surge public` but when i put in the arbiterary domain name it did not work.

when I left the temporarily domain name provided by surge and also, after I verified my email address, it works fine.